# Problem connecting to a PostgreSQL database with Common SQL

Tags: postgresql, path, common-lisp, dyld, lispworks

I'm working on Lispworks 8.0.1, and using the Common SQL interface provided by the software.

On the other hand I'm working with PostgreSQL and I want to connect a PostgreSQL database in LispWorks.

Here are the lines I use (following the [lispworks guidelines](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/RNIG/html/readme-88.htm)) and the [Common SQL tutorial](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/sql-tutorial/):

```
(load-all-patches)
(require "postgresql")
(sql:initialize-database-type :database-type :postgresql)
```

The first two lines work perfectly but on the third line I get the following error :

```
Could not register handle for external module "-lpq" : dlopen(libpq, 0x0005): tried: 'libpq'
(relative path not allowed in hardened program),
'/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibpq' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libpq' (no such file,
not in dyld cache), 'libpq' (relative path not allowed in hardened program), '/usr/lib/libpq'
(no such file, not in dyld cache).
```

I downloaded libqp through homebrew and also it is well written in the documentation that

```
For database-type :oracle, :mysql and :postgresql, if the client library is not installed in a standard place, its directory must be added to the environment variable DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH (see the OS manual entry for dyld).
```

so I configured the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH in the .bash_profile file

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpq
```

It didn't work so I tried with the .zshrc file the following line:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpq"
```

The error is still the same.

So, does anyone have encountered the same problem and/or has an idea how I can solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Does the directory `/usr/lib/` exist in your machine? If so why not symlink `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpq` to there as that is one of the places the program is looking for it.

Comment: What does `(lw:environment-variable "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH")` say?  If `nil` that's probably symptomatic of something.  However you would probably get a better answer on the Lisp-HUG mailing list than here.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The /usr/lib is in read-only mode, I can't paste or make a symlink to that directory. As for : (lw:environment-variable "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"), it indeed sends nil. I'll got to the Lisp-hug mailing list as indicated